# Customize adoc-mode

Tags: emacs, asciidoc

I have quite a hard time finding documentation on `adoc-mode`, the Emacs mode for Asciidoc.  In particular, I would like to customize the faces for titles (they are quite too large for me.)

I installed it through `M-x list-packages` (version `20220720.622`.)

Any pointer on how to configure `adoc-mode`?  Any tip?

Comment: Bozhidar Batsov posted on Aug 30 in the Asciidoctor Chat that "after 7 years of dormancy the AsciiDoc mode for Emacs (adoc-mode) is once again under active maintenance". You can check https://github.com/bbatsov/adoc-mode for source code and a little documentation

Comment: I didn't realize it had been so long :-o  This is excellent news, thank you for letting me know!